# How to bulk insert data to mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

Currently i'm using Alchemy as a ORM, and I look for a way to speed up my insert operation, I have bundle of XML files to import

```
for name in names:
    p=Product()
    p.name="xxx"
    session.commit()
```

i use above code to insert my data paser from batch xml file to mysql,it's very slow
also i tried to

```
for name in names:
    p=Product()
    p.name="xxx"
session.commit()
```

but it seems didn't change anything

Comment: @mizboy you would need to provide more info. Just not enough info to suggest speed optimization. Provide current queries etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bypass the ORM for the insertion operation and use the [SQL Expression generator](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html?highlight=insert#insert-expressions) instead.

Something like:

```
conn.execute(Product.insert(), [dict(name=name) for name in names])
```

That should create a single statement to do your inserting.

That example was taken from [lower down the same page](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html?highlight=insert#executing-multiple-statements).

(I'd be interested to know what speedup you got from that)

Comment: finally i use mysqlimport cmd tool instead,it's really quick,but should build a csv file